# How to check if a string contains any letter besides Z

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to check to see if this object contains any letters besides Z and if it does it should return Null. The way I have it initialized gives me no errors but when testing it does not actually return null if a letter is present.

```
if(request.DoorTag.Contains(@"[a - yA - Y]"))
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What you code does it it checks if a string does actually contain a string "[a - yA - Y]". You need to use class `Regex` to use regular expressions.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a regex. I'm not sure that `Contains` is a method that accepts a regex...

Answer (score 2):

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(request.DoorTag, "[a-yA-Y]")
{
    return null;
}
```

But `"[^zZ]"` would even be better, since it'll check that your `DoorTag` contains any other char than `Z`

Comment: I don't know if I'd recommend `"[^zZ]"` since OP is specifically asking about letters.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb `é` is a letter which is not within the range `a-y`...

Comment: Well yeah, but what I'm getting at is that you'll also catch something like `"1234"`, which has no letters but would be found by `"[^zZ]"`.

Comment: it seems after doing that it is nulling that whole object with this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Any Tips on this one?

Comment: is request null? is DoorTag null? @atlmkecode

Comment: its turning the doorTag null